# Wordpress website db connection error

Tags: database, wordpress

I came over this serious problem. 
My WordPress website was running all right. suddenly It showed the page of WordPress installation. so, I quickly registered a user and so on. Then it showed "db connection error". I went to my server and tried to log into my phpmyadmin but the password didn't work. This kept happening for 5 mins. then thing worked normal again.

1- is this a hacker attack?
2- how do I prevent the page of WP installation from showing up if the db connection goes down again? because this is a desaster

- how do I prevent wp-admin from showing the name of my db in the db connection error ? Better preventing any error report from my website when anything is down?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nobody can tell you whether it was hacker related without a lot more information.  There should be logs on the machine hosting your site--I would check them first to see if you can tell if the database went down and why.  If you don't admin your own site you can ask your hosting provider what the problem was--they may have been rebooting a database machine, for example.

I would also do a full backup of your site and database in case there is any hardware trouble you don't know about.

In the meantime, if you administer the site yourself, take a look at advice for hardening Wordpress: http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress

Comment: Thanks for your help. My most important question for now. How do I prevent the re-install process from showing up to normal user when DB is down? also how to prevent "db connection error" to show up especially telling details about the db name in wp-admin?

Comment: It doesn't show up for me if I turn off my database server.  I would make sure your install is up to date.  It is also possible you have WP_DEBUG set in your configuration file--if so, remove it.

Comment: You could also change the text it is showing, although that won't necessarily persist across updates.  It looks like the error message is generated in wp-includes/wp-db.php

Comment: I checked that wp_debug is set to false. Why do you think then the installation process went over again when the DB is down? I talked to my server admin and they told me there is no errors shown in the log

Comment: No idea.  The only explanation that comes to mind is someone made a change and changed it back.  (E.g. it was connecting to an empty database for a minute because of a change to a database or Wordpress, so it thought it hadn't been installed.)  But that's just a theory which happens to fit the facts.